# If setting off nukes creates "nuclear winters", why don't we set off a few nukes to offset global warming?

Tags: geophysics

I mean nuclear weapon testing is nothing new and was done in the not so far past.

A few explosions strategically placed in the upper atmosphere should do the trick,,,right?

Comment: I guess you're not considering the effects of the radiation being dumped into the atmosphere. That might have created a few more problems than solved.

Comment: Because annihilating huge swaths of our planet with nuclear fallout is not a good idea…

Comment: A much easier and less dangerous way to achieve the same result is simply to get a few volcanoes to erupt. They would pour lots of dust into the atmosphere and achieve your goal. This is well known.  Of course this is only a temporary solution while the dust floats around. You would need to do it every couple of years to provide a permanent solution.

Comment: That would be the upper atmosphere with the ozone layer that damaging helped get us into this mess in the first place ?

Answer (score 11):

> A few explosions strategically placed in the upper atmosphere should do the trick, right ?

Wrong, for at least two reasons:

1. The ["nuclear winter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_winter) effect is caused not by the nuclear explosions themselves but by the soot dispersed into the stratosphere by the firestorms that they create. For firestorms you need ground level explosions.
2. The modelling that generated the "nuclear winter" results assumed between one hundred and one thousand firestorms, so many more than "a few".

Comment: Good answer! Bravo! So why then don't spray the atmosphere with this "soot" or goo you are talking about using airliners special modified airplanes military craft etc... Surely since we can manipulate the climate of the planet we could make some more climate engineering to the right direction! There must a feasible technological solution to the problem? IMHO, why fix it if it is BIG BUSINESS !!lol